# Increased minSdkVersion, how to let users know?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-console

I have increased the `minSdkVersion` from 16 to 19. This will affect a small number of users, but I would like to let them know about the changes.

How can I identify which users will be affected by these changes? I know I can get a list of devices (model name, etc.) from the Google Play Store, but that isn't very helpful to me if I want to email the affected users. Is there a way to get the device ID (or some other unique identifier) to match them against my database of users, maybe through Firebase?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is that you can show some notifications about the changes before you make it official.

Check the android version in your code:

```
If (Build.Version.SDK <= KitKat)
```

Then show a notification such as: "Your android version will be no longer supported soon, please upgrade to newer android versions!" (specifying a date would be recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Why not initially when your users are registering their devices/data, also collect device like:

> ```
> System.getProperty("os.version"); // OS version
> android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK      // API Level
> android.os.Build.DEVICE           // Device
> android.os.Build.MODEL            // Model 
> android.os.Build.PRODUCT          // Product
> ```

of course this will not work for existing databas but that can be fixed if you push an update containing this, and then all users who update to latest version will register their model. Now you can in your backen email the affected users

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to get access to users emails because it violates privacy policy.

There is also no need for that. After your release the new version, the update will not be rolled out to devices with lower SDK Versions. Users of such devices will not be able to install the application again, but the older version will not be removed from devices, on which it was already installed.

A short explanation will be present in the Google Play application.